# In Views, display additional fields from an entity reference

Tags: views, 8, nodes

I have a content type with a field that is an entity reference to another content type called "URLs", and the "*Allowed number of values*" is set to "*Unlimited*", meaning that one record can have multiple URLs associated to it.

When I come to the View for this node, I have added a Field for "URLs", and under "**MULTIPLE FIELD SETTINGS**" I have ticked "*Display all values in the same row*", and **Display type**: *Unordered list*.

This works well, and I get the the list of associated URLs in an unordered list, like so:

- www.domain1.com
- www.domain2.com
- www.domain3.com

Where it gets complicated, my "URLs" content type has another field called "field_url_type", which is a field type "**List (text)**". This contains the *type of URL*, (eg. Production, Development, Staging, Decommissioned, etc).

In the main content type display View, I would like to display this additional field from the URL content type next to the URL values, like so:

- www.domain1.com (Production)
- www.domain2.com (Development)
- www.domain3.com (Decommissioned)

I tried using the Views > Configure Field > REWRITE RESULTS panel to include the REPLACEMENT PATTERNS for both fields, like so:

```
{{ field_url }} ({{ field_url_type }})
```

... but this didn't work. I'm guessing it is more complicated than that!

Does anyone know how I can display this additional field from a content type referenced by an entity reference field in a node view?

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions for this but to pick one :)

- Download and enable Display Suite https://www.drupal.org/project/ds
- Go to *admin/structure/ds/fields* and a token field (see screenshot #2 for values, adjust according to your field names)
- Go to view mode of your Url content type and create a seperate view mode, e.g. called **entity_reference_url_view** or something (I just picked **teaser** for this example) . Make sure to select One column layout so Display suite will make your custom token field available to you (see screenshot #1)
- add the custom token field you added earlier to the visible section
- Now go to your other content type view at e.g. *admin/structure/types/manage/your_content_type/display/full* and select **Rendered Entity** as the *format* and choose your previously created view mode of the URL content type (see screenshot #3
- Now view your content type and the entity reference fields should show up in the format you defined in your custom Display suite field

Screenshot #1
[image]

Screenshot #2
[image]

Screenshot #3
[image]

Comment: Thanks @undersound, I will give this a go and report back!